# Dropbox account used on two computers different folder sizes

Tags: macos, dropbox

I have my Dropbox account setup on an iMac and a MacBook Air. When I check the folder size of a folder on the Dropbox account in Finder on the iMac it will say the file size is about **45,9** MB while on the MacBook Air it will say **41,4** MB. I can't understand why there is this difference? I've tried to unlink my account and set it up again on my MacBook Air but it's still the same issue.

Comment: Is this size of files, or size on disk? What are the sector sizes of the drives? MBA most likely has an SSD, versus an HDD in the iMac, which could be a factor. Have you run `rsync` in read-only mode to compare the two folders?

Comment: Both computers have SSDs. I'm checking the folder size through the Finder (Apple-I) on the same folder in the Dropbox folder. No I haven't run `rsync`. I've just done this quick comparison.

Comment: Do both use the same version of OS X? Does it happen to all folders or just one in particular? Can you observe the same thing with single files? Could you post screenshots of the `Info` window (i.e. press `Cmd-I` for the folder/file)?